# angular i18next::backendConnector loaded correctly, but translations not available in controller

Tags: angularjs, i18next

I init i18next:

```
if (window.i18next) {
window.i18next.use(window.i18nextXHRBackend) ;
window.i18next.use(window.i18nextSprintfPostProcessor);
window.i18next.init({
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        lng: 'en',
        resGetPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/camps.json',
        backend: {
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/camps.json'
        },
    }, function (err, t) {
        return i18next ;
        console.log('resources loaded',t);
        var translate = i18next.t("nav");
        console.log("translate variable = " + translate);
    });
};

app = angular.module("ngCamps", ['ngSanitize', 'jm.i18next' , 'ngAnimate', 'ui.select']) ;
```

then in my controller:

```
app.controller("myController", ($scope, $http, $filter, $q, $i18next ) =>     {
    const resources = i18next.getResourceBundle('en','camps') ;
    console.log("resources",resources) ;
    $scope.hello = i18next.t("nav");
    console.log($scope.hello) ;
```

.....
And the translation json is not available when the page loads.
But after the page load I get a console that tells me the resource was loaded

The console looks like this:

```
i18next::translator: missingKey undefined translation nav nav
```

... then
    i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translation for language en

and if i enter in console - i get the correct translation:

```
i18next.t('nav');
"My Camp"
```

So it seems that the page loads before the translation is available in the controller.

How can i change that? 
thanks for your help.

Comment: Loading translations like every xhr request is async -> assert callback was called before bootstrapping -> you might check at https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next how it was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$i18next.t` when `i18nextLanguageChange` event fired, like this:

```
app.controller('myController', ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter, $q, $i18next) => {

  $scope.hello = '';

  $rootScope.$on('i18nextLanguageChange', function () {
    $scope.hello = $i18next.t('nav');
    console.log($scope.hello);
  });
```

Example: https://github.com/i18next/ng-i18next/blob/master/examples/provider/provider1.js